# what access is missing in my id to check MQ status?

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

Linux Environment - IBM MQ v9.1

User id "user_01" is used to login VM1 & VM2. MQ is installed on both the VMs.
MQ data & log disk(SAN) is shared and controlled using Veritas Cluster Manager.
"user_01" is part of mqm group.

when i login to VM1 or VM2 using id "user_01", "dspmq" command shows qmgr status as "Status not available"
eg,

> QMNAME(PARIS_QM)     STATUS(Status not available)

After I switch to mqm id, i'm able to check the qmgr status.

> QMNAME(PARIS_QM)   STATUS(Running)

I'm not sure what is preventing id "user_01" to see qmgr status.

setmqinst command is run & "dspmqver" command works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to read the `qmstatus.ini` normally located in `/var/mqm/qmgrs/PARIS_QM/` or equivalent if your data directory is different.

Answer (score 0):

Access to the qmstatus.ini looks like missing for the second user id. Please recheck if it has proper access rights defined.